# Following JSON Api with rswag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, json-api, rswag

I'm using [rswag](https://github.com/rswag/rswag) to test a rather common RubyOnRails [JSON Api](https://jsonapi.org/) application, but I can't figure out a rather common case where I upload a file to an endpoint.

The endpoint expects the usual `data` attribute in the request body with a `file` attribute containing the binary, and I cannot make rswag to generate a request with the correct parameters.

```
  path '/documents' do
    post 'Creates a document' do
      tags 'Documents'
      consumes 'multipart/form-data'
      produces 'application/vnd.api+json'

      parameter name: 'data',
                description: 'Whatever',
                attributes: {
                  schema: {
                    type: :object,
                    properties: {
                      file: { type: :binary },
                    },
                  },
                }

      response '201', 'success' do
        let(:data) do
          {
            attributes: {
              file: Rack::Test::UploadedFile.new($REALARGS),
            },
          }
        end

        schema "$ref": '#/definitions/post_document_responses/201'

        run_test! do |_example|
          # ACTUAL TEST
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

There are some other simpler parameters (Authorization for example) that are correctly generated, I'm then sure `rswag` is hooked correctly.
The request I'm seeing has no parameters, I can remove the `data` parameter and nothing changes. I've tried a million combinations, always the same result and I don't know what's going on.

The `params` the controller expects is `data[attributes][file]`.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `parameter` block needs to specify where it will be inserted. There's an [example spec](https://github.com/rswag/rswag/blob/0def9fad6fbfc97168d0e1ffc740c115e00c0768/test-app/spec/integration/blogs_spec.rb) where I found a reference to `:formData`, which it turns out *must* be set (i.e. you can't use `:body`, it just sends an empty request).

After a bit of jiggery-pokery I managed to get your example working with the nested attribute in the form data:

```
path '/documents' do
  post 'Creates a document' do
    tags 'Documents'
    consumes 'multipart/form-data'
    produces 'application/vnd.api+json'

    parameter name: 'data[attributes][file]',
              description: 'Whatever',
              in: :formData,
              attributes: {
                schema: {
                  type: :object,
                  properties: {
                    file: { type: :binary },
                  },
                },
              }

    response '201', 'success' do
      let(:"data[attributes][file]") { Rack::Test::UploadedFile.new(Rails.root.join("spec/requests/api/v1/documents_post_spec.rb")) }
      end

      schema "$ref": '#/definitions/post_document_responses/201'

      run_test! do |_example|
        # ACTUAL TEST
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to send an array of objects with files you can do something like this:

```rb
parameter name: 'documents', in: :formData, type: :array, required: true

let(:documents) do
  [
    {
     file: file_1,
     name: '...' 
    },
    {
     file: file_2,
     name: '...'
    }
  ]
end
```